# Comparing pevious state with current/new state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to compare the `prevState` with the  `this.state` but not sure if that's possible. `prevState` seems to be available to `setState` function but I don't need to set the state. I just need to check if the one of the state variable has changed from previous values then I need to take a certain action. I understand I could use `componentDidUpdate` to know if something has changed but I need to compare one specific state value to it's previous value.

It might be possible using new React hooks but I am using classes and switching to hooks isn't a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare specific state value in componentDidUpdate itself:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if(prevState.value !== this.state.value) {
     // perform the action
   }
}
```